# jQuery .append() messes up positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a webpage in which the user can add objects and drag them around using jQuery-UI. The code used to add the objects (which can be images or text) can be summarized this way:

```
function createObject($inner) {
    var $newObject = $("<div></div>").append($inner)
    .attr(/* some attributes */)
    .css(/* some css (which makes the position relative) */)
    .appendTo($father);
}
```

When I create the first object, I have no problems. However, each subsequent object uses the end of the previous object as it's (0;0) coordinate, like so:

```
+----------++----------+
| object A || object B |
+----------++----------+
```

The coordinates of object B are now (0;0), even though it clearly is not on the top left corner. Does someone know why this is the case?

Comment: Each newly created div is being appended to whatever `$father` is (not shown in the question), so isn't it normal for them to appear one after the other as sibling children of `$father`? Regarding the coordinates of object B being (0,0), the comment in the code says it is `position:relative`, so its zero point is not the top left corner of its parent and that is normal too...

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that its zero point is that corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use CSS position property to be absolute

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

```
position:absolute;
```

In addition, you have to ensure that the the $father you are referring to is always the same.

This can be done by creating a div/container block with position:absolute and add all newly added elements into that blok.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that doesn't solve the problem